# XPath command returns nothing - XML schemas

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm writing an XSLT code transforming an XML schema to another.
I want to use the value of attributes from the input schema.

Here is my XML schema i want to change :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema SCCOAMCD:desc="" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" version="3.2.1ec" xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" xmlns:SCCOAMCD="urn:SCCOA-schemaInfo" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:complexType name="typeAssociation">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="refid" type="xsd:QName"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeString">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeBoolean">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:boolean"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeShort">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:short"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeInteger">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeReal">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:float"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeDouble">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeDecimal">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeAnnee">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:gYear"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeAnneeMois">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:gYearMonth"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeDate">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:date"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeHeure">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:time"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeDTG">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:dateTime"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeAnyURI">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyURI"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeDatatypeChaine1a2000">
    <xsd:restriction base="typeString">
        <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
        <xsd:maxLength value="2000"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="typeDatatypeChaine1a30">
    <xsd:restriction base="typeString">
        <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
        <xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType SCCOAMCD:desc="Une caractéristique intangible d&apos;intérêt militaire qui est spécifiée administrativement, peut être représentée par une figure géométrique, et est associée à la conduite des opérations militaires" SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.ElementControle" name="ElementControle">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element SCCOAMCD:desc="a_pour_etat" SCCOAMCD:relation="A-SC.ElementControle,EtatEltControle" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="a_pour_etat" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:EtatEltControle"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType SCCOAMCD:desc="Etat" SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.Etat" name="Etat">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element SCCOAMCD:attribut="A-SC.Etat.Commentaires" SCCOAMCD:desc="Commentaires sur l&apos;état" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="commentaires" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:typeDatatypeChaine1a2000"/>
        <xsd:element SCCOAMCD:attribut="A-SC.Etat.GdhDebut" SCCOAMCD:desc="Date début de validité de l&apos;état" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="gdhDebut" type="typeDTG"/>
        <xsd:element SCCOAMCD:attribut="A-SC.Etat.GdhFin" SCCOAMCD:desc="GDH estimé du retour opérationnel ou date prochain état" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="gdhFin" type="typeDTG"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType SCCOAMCD:desc="Description de l&apos;état d&apos;une zone ou d&apos;une sous zone" SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.EtatEltControle" name="EtatEltControle">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.Etat" base="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:Etat">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element SCCOAMCD:attribut="A-SC.EtatEltControle.Etat" SCCOAMCD:desc="Dictionnaire précisant l&apos;état de disponibilité d&apos;un élément de contrôle" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="etat" type="typeString"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType SCCOAMCD:desc="Portion de l&apos;espace aérien pour lequel peuvent-être définis :" SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.ZoneAerienne" name="ZoneAerienne">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.ElementControle" base="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:ElementControle">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element SCCOAMCD:attribut="A-SC.ZoneAerienne.Code" SCCOAMCD:desc="Code identifiant la zone Aérienne de manière unique hors ACO et ATO" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="code" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:typeDatatypeChaine1a30"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:element name="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:type_SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA"/>
 <xsd:complexType name="type_SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Header" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:type_SCCOA_header"/>
        <xsd:element name="Entities" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:type_Data_SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="type_SCCOA_header">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element fixed="1.0" name="VersionSchemaSCCOA" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Nom" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Commentaire" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Classification" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="type_Data_SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA">
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
        <xsd:element name="ZoneAerienne" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:ZoneAerienne"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

In the last schema i want to select the value of the name and the type of last tag.

```
> "SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA"
> "SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:type_SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA"
```

I tried the following XSLT's code without success :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>


<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsd xdt err fn"
xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect"
extension-element-prefixes="redirect"
xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">

<!-- Pour avoir bonne indentation en sortie -->

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>


<!-- Transformation identité -->


<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<!-- Création de nos nouveaux noeuds -->
<xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
    <!-- on crée à nouveau le schema-->
    <xsd:schema xmlns:nr0="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm" >
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
        <!-- on copie ce qu'il y avait déjà dans le schéma -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <!-- on remet tous les éléments enfants du schéma -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <!-- on crée notre propre branche pour appeler notre complexType-->
        <xsl:call-template name="mapping"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="baliseRacine"/>

    </xsd:schema>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="mapping">
    <xsl:element name="xsd:complexType">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">mapping</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="xsd:sequence">
                <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="xsd:schema/xsd:element/@name"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="occurs">
                        <xsl:value-of select="xsd:schema/xsd:element/@type"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="baliseRacine">
    <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">plugin</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="xsd:complexType">
            <xsl:element name="xsd:sequence">
                <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">mapping</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">mapping</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is what my XML schema transformed by this :

```
<xsd:complexType name="mapping">
  <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="" occurs=""/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I can't find why nothing is selected with my XPath.

Comment: I would really suggest you start with an XPath tutorial before trying to use XPath in XSLT. So your subject says "XPath error", which error exactly do you get? Consider to share any necessary information. As for selecting that `xsd:element`, you write a condition like `name="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA"` in your informal description, if that is one of the criterias to select the element, shoudn't it appear in the XPath with e.g. `xsd:schema/xsd:element[@name = 'SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA']`? Or if you wan the last top-level `xsd:element`, have you tried `xsd:schema/xsd:element[last()]`?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, you are completely right. My question was put in the wrong way. I edited it.

Comment: So we now know you don't get anything selected but we can't tell why as you haven't shown a complete and minimal sample to allow us to understand, reproduce and fix the problem as all you have shown is a single named template, without any context, without any used namespace declarations. Unless we see where the `xsd` prefix used in your XPath expressions is mapped to and see where and in which context the named template is called we can't tell what goes wrong. The used paths make sense if you call the template in the context of the document node `/` and of course with `xsd` mapped correctly.

Comment: I show you my complete XML schema, i thought you had all you need to answer.

Comment: No, we need a complete, minimal XSLT as well. Otherwise, we have no idea what other kinds of templates it has, what namespaces are declared, etc.

Comment: I hope it is better now. Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `xsd:schema` element is the context node and you want to select a child `xsd:element` you need to adapt your paths to

```
<xsl:template name="mapping">
    <xsl:element name="xsd:complexType">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">mapping</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="xsd:sequence">
                <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="xsd:element/@name"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="occurs">
                        <xsl:value-of select="xsd:element/@type"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Or better yet use literal result elements and attribute value templates

```
<xsl:template name="mapping">
  <xsd:complexType name="mapping">
  <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="{xsd:element/@name}" occurs="{xsd:element/@type}"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and your answer.